# Sphinx decorated classes not documented

Tags: python, python-sphinx, python-decorators, autodoc

I'm documenting my library with Sphinx. And I have decorator `logic_object`:

```
class logic_object:
    """Decorator for logic object class.
    """
    def __init__(self, cls):
        self.cls = cls
        self.__doc__ = self.cls.__doc__
```

And I have `gravity` class that decorated by `logic_object`:

```
@logic_object
class gravity:
    """Basic gravity object logic class.

    :param float g: pixels of acceleration
    :param float jf: jump force
    """
#There is more not important code.
```

My Sphinx `.rst` file is:

```
Mind.Existence
========================
Classes, methods and functions marked with * aren't for usual cases, they are made to help to the rest of the library.

.. automodule:: Mind.Existence
   :members:
   :member-order: bysource
```

`logic_object` gets documented with `autodoc`, but `gravity` doesn't.

Why this happens and how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because the decorated class is not a real class object (not an instance of `type`), and therefore autodoc does not know how to document it.

To fix it, you must write a custom documenter (e.g. in your conf.py):

```
from Mind.Existence import logic_object
from sphinx.ext.autodoc import ClassDocumenter

class MyClassDocumenter(ClassDocumenter):
    objtype = 'logic_object'
    directivetype = 'class'

    @classmethod
    def can_document_member(cls, member, membername, isattr, parent):
        return isinstance(member, logic_object)

def setup(app):
    app.add_autodocumenter(MyClassDocumenter)
```

And then (in your decorator) you must also copy `__name__`  and `__bases__` from the decorated object::

```
def __init__(self, cls):
    self.cls = cls
    self.__doc__ = cls.__doc__
    self.__name__ = cls.__name__
    self.__bases__ = cls.__bases__
```

HTH,
Luc